# If[ ] not evaluating properly inside NDSolve[ ]

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve a set of equations with the NDSolve. I encounter an error which I try to explain it with the below example.

```
q[u_] := 1;

s = NDSolve[{

Sum[If[u == n[t], q[u], q[u] + 5], {u, 1}] y''[t] == -1000 y[t], 
y'[0] == 0, y[0] == 1, n[0] == 1, WhenEvent[t > 3.5, n[t] -> 2]}, 

{y}, {t, 0, 7}, DiscreteVariables -> {n}];

Plot[y[t] /. s, {t, 0, 7}]
```

[image]

As you can see when `q[u_] := 1` I have the result but when I define the `q[u_]` as a function of `u`, for example `q[u_] := u` which should give me the same result as the above figure, I recieve this error

> Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a "problem" due to the holding attributes of `If[ ]`. You may inject the value 
by using `With[{pp=u},If[....]]` inside your `Sum[]` or with something like this:

```
q[u_] := u

s = NDSolve[{
    (Total[If[# == n[t], n[t] q[#] , q[#]] & /@ Range@2] ) y''[ t] == -100 y[t],
    y'[0] == 0, y[0] == 1, n[0] == 1,
    WhenEvent[t > 3.5, n[t] -> 2]}, {y, n}, {t, 0, 7}, 
   DiscreteVariables -> {n}];

Plot[y[t] /. s, {t, 0, 7}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you so much.  Both solutions work well.
`Sum[With[{u = u}, If[u == n[t], q[u], q[u] + 5]], {u, 1}]`